# Some SFSymbols not appearing on older iOS versions even when targeted

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, sf-symbols

I forked a year old code base from a production [Deaf assistant app](https://deafassistant.com) that works perfectly fine. Then I created a [conference live captioning app](https://conferencecaptioning.com) build using the lastest Xcode version, while all settings stayed the same.
All the functionality works fine in the new app that has minimum target framework of iOS 14, but I noticed that some of the icons from the SF symbols are messed up in one of my test devices running iOS 14. They worked perfectly fine in the debug build when I installed on a simulator through Xcode.

Have you faced this issue? What do you recommend I can do to debug further?

On the tutorial page screenshot below, this is what was supposed to display the icon

```
HStack{
    Text("\(Image(systemName: "bell.and.waveform.fill")) ")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("SecondaryColor"))
    Text(NSLocalizedString("Conference - Connect with streams in the conference rooms to get the live captions", comment: "CONFERENCE") + "\n") // TODO: Use idiom instead of device
                        .font(Font.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
                        .foregroundColor(Color("SecondaryColor"))
}
```

[image: Missing in-line icons from text]
[image: Missing sf symbols from list icons]
[image: Missing Navbar icon]

Comment: I am not able to edit the question, but I figured out the issue! I recently had to get a replacement for my iPhone 12, and I didn't realized it needs to be updated from iOS 14. When I tested the same code on the old iPhone running iOS 16.5, all the SF Symbols appeared again. So clearly the issue is that they added newer SF symbols that weren't there in older OS versions which is why it wasn't appearing on the phone.

Comment: Everyone knows that different ios versions contain different sets of symbol images. No need for this question to be reopened. Just delete it.

Comment: @matt yeah I would think that the minimum SDK version took care of the logic

Comment: Well the images are Optionals. That takes care of the logic. You have to check if it's nil.

Comment: @matt do you if there’s a way to know which iOS version was a symbol introduced in?

Comment: @Saamer The SF Symbols app shows the availability of each symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to be very careful when choosing which SF symbols you use in the app. The minimum SDK version doesn’t take care of the SF Symbols logic, and so some SF symbols only appear on newer OS versions.

Even though my app minimum SDK version is 14.0, I downloaded the app from the App Store on an iOS 14.5 app and it didn’t support those specific symbols that are not appearing. When opening the app on the latest iOS 16.5, they do appear.

As @HangarRash pointed out, you can check the SF symbols app to see the SF Symbols version availability. Tap on the SF Symbol version to get details on OS version
[image: Screenshot from the SF Symbols app]
[image: Screenshot Expanding the versioning for more details]

Comment: The versioning is more details than you are showing. Expand "Monochrome", for example, and it shows specific OS versions for the symbol, not just the SF Symbols 3.0 version shown where the arrow is pointing in your screenshot.

Comment: Ah I though it mean iOS 3.0 lol, good catch @HangarRash updated!

Comment: Yeah, SF Symbols weren't introduced until iOS 13.0 so no symbol can be used with iOS 12 or earlier.